# JGraphT: Inconsistent graph size for same dataset

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

**Version**: 1.3.0

**Graph Requirement**: Child will have many parents or none.

**Data Node**: Id + List [Parent ids]

```
class Node {
    String id;
    List<String> parents;
}
```

**Total dataset**: 3500 nodes.

GraphType is selected using : *Directed + No Multiple Edges + No Self Loops + No Weights + DefaultEdge*

**Graph Building logic**:

- Iterate through 3500 nodes
- Create the vertex using node ID.
- Graph.addVertex(childVertex)
- then check if parents exists
- if they do, iterate through parents
- Create parent id vertex using parent id.
- Graph.addVertex(parentVertex)
- Graph.addEdge(parentVertex, childvertex)

However, running the same dataset (3500), for 5 times, I am getting different graph size calculated every time using: *graph.vertexSet().size()*. Expectation is 3500 everytime but its inconsistent.

All 3500 ids are unique and we should have graph size = 3500 but we got something like:
GraphType is - SimpleDirectedGraph and size is variable - 3500, 3208, 3283, 2856, 3284.

Any help would appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: The current question is not suitable for stackoverflow. At the very least, include a minimal working example that exhibits the problem. It is impossible to provide feedback based on the bullet points provided.